# Drupal, Solr & Facet Api - Persistent facet links in blocks

Tags: search, solr, drupal-7, drupal-modules, faceted-search

I need to produce facet block from two vocabularies in my site. I am using Views and a patched version of Views infinite Scroll to generate the search page, using my search index, and I have tweaked everything I could in the facet display settings to see if I could produce the requested results, to no avail.

I do not need keyword searches. I need to show all taxonomy terms in each facets at all times and to be able to select a single criteria at a time from each vocabulary. So, never more thane one selection at a time from each facet block.

Why are you using Solr to store data and generate your search page, if you do not need keyword search and are trying to go against the native working of solr Facets, I hear you say? For performance reasons, it is the reason why I am using Solr to store & serve the results, I have even gone as far as pushing renedered node to the index with the help of the somwhat obscure search_api_solr_view_modes module.

#### I could take two separate routes

1. Create a custom block, load all the taxonomy terms, alter the output of the term link to point to the view and provide the TID for the View. The active filter data could be obtained from the view arguments. I know how to do that but feel it is the wrong way to go about it, if I am working with Solr, I should be using a facet, not a custom block.
2. Build a custom Facet block that has this exact behaviour. After reading a lot of documentation, I git kind of dicouraged with the possibility of doing this simply without having to develop a Facet  plugin, which is kind of out of my league.

Any advice is appreciated.

Here is a screenshot of the interface I have to produce.
http://imageshack.com/a/img834/9836/kr0i.png

- Each taxonomy term has to be persistent, i.e., produce a link event if there are no nodes indexed under this term.
- Selecting a term in one of the vocabularies will deselect previously selected terms
- Clicking on the x next to a term will remove it form the active search criterias.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this. https://drupal.org/project/ajax_facets This might get you to where you need to be. Sans you infinite scroll. There is a youtube video that goes with it. http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pBj3OkXLyWs

I'd appreciate it if it works as I haven't tried it my self.